# How to return data from function by fetch() in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I created a FlastList for my posts where I calling a function that made for returning the likes of the post but it's giving me an error that is :

```
[Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in RCTView (at Testing.js:196)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (at Testing.js:185)
    in RCTView (at Testing.js:184)
    in RCTView (at Testing.js:165)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (at Testing.js:160)
    in RCTView (at VirtualizedList.js:1925)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:767)
    in RCTView (at ScrollView.js:1038)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1178)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1183)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:676)
    in FlatList (at Testing.js:151)
    in RCTView (at Testing.js:147)
    in Testing
    in SceneView (at StackView.tsx:269)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:171)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:170)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:442)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:435)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:431)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:424)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:138)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:503)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:110)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:496)
    in RCTView (at CardStack.tsx:93)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:403)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:384)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:382)
    in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:26)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:34)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:379)
    in StackView (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:33)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)]
```

fetch() is working properly I'm getting the likes but when I return the data I got that error.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error and how it will remove and how I'll get posts like on my app.

Here is my code.

```
likes = async item => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://192.168.0.3:1234/post_likes?post_id=' + item.id,
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    let likes = data[0].likes;
    console.log(likes);
    return <Text>{likes}</Text>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HeaderIcon />
        {this.state.loading && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="cyan" />}

        <FlatList
          onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
            if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
              this.getMorePost();
            }
          }}
          data={this.state.post}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              style={styles.main}
              onPress={() => {
                this.openPost(item);
              }}>
              <View style={styles.main}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                  {/* <View>{this.img(item)}</View> */}
                  <View>
                    <Image
                      style={styles.profilePic}
                      source={{uri: item.featuredImage}}
                    />
                  </View>

                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.post_title}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <Image
                  // resizeMode="stretch"
                  style={styles.image}
                  source={{uri: item.featuredImage}}
                />
                <View>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPress={() => {
                      Share.share({
                        title: item.post_title,
                        message:
                          item.section_seo_url +
                          item.post_content.replace(/<[^>]*>|&nbsp;/g, ' ') +
                          item.featuredImage,
                        url: item.featuredImage,
                      });
                    }}>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        padding: 10,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                      }}>
                      <Image
                        source={require('../image/wlogo.png')}
                        style={{height: 40, width: 40, paddingLeft: 50}}
                      />
                      {this.likes(item)}
                    </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are getting your likes in your log Right ???

Comment: yes I'm getting likes in log with this error..

Comment: this.state.post : show me your  only one post data

Comment: [{"id":597,"post_title":"आखिर क्यों महिलाओं को शमशान में जाना मना हैं ? जाने ","customize_category":29,"section_category":"Lokpriya","section_product":"86","weekday":"Thursday","trending":"No","start_date":null,"end_date":null,"section_seo_url":"https://www.prabhubhakti.com/why-women-are-not-allowed-to-go-to-the-crematorium","featuredImage":"https://i.imgur.com/dyE424n.jpg","post_content":"","latest_on_top":"","tag":"burial sites , crematorium , shamshan "}]

Comment: this type of data are inside my this.state.post

Comment: you are making  'http://192.168.0.3:1234/post_likes?post_id=' + item.id for your all post Right.

Comment: this will make many calls as no of your post's

Comment: instead of doing this try to get your likes detail with your post data

Comment: likes are not inside my post data I'm getting likes from another table of MySQL database with using node.js and express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per me here you are making multiple api calls

```
Instead of that you can get your posts data with your likes from backend in simple 
one api call.

You just need to add join query with your likes table in your get-posts request 
which will return all your post with likes 

So, you will get your all post with likes in one api call instead of these much 
of calls.

Which is good practise for us.it will increase your app performance as well as
less api calls so it is good for server as well
```

Solution is like

```
 add one more field likes to your post table 

 what you can do is when user like/dislike your post then get your likes
 from post table and increment by one else decrement by one as per user 
 like/dislike and update back to post table.
```

Comment: My likes table is like:
`id post_id  user like
1 23   Tarun 1
2 24   Tarun 0`

where like = 1 is considered as like or 0 is considered as dislike
so how can I join these two tables